# how to write a string to csv?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

help please write data horizontally in csv-file.

the following code writes [this](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/tt1.png):

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows('jgjh')
```

but I need [so](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/tt2.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `csv` module deals in *sequences*; use `writer.writerow()` (singular) and give it a list of one column:

```
writer.writerow(['jgjh'])
```

The `.writerow()` method will take each element in the sequence you give it and make it one column. Best to give it a list of columns, and `['jgjh']` makes one such column.

`.writerows()` (plural) expects a sequence of such rows; for your example you'd have to wrap the one row into another list to make it a series of rows, so `writer.writerows([['jgjh']])` would also achieve what you want.